# Crystal Report Cross Tab Calculated Member as text

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I'vre created a cross tab report with 2 calculated Member to be able to have the difference between 2 column and the percentage of this difference in CR 2011. What I want to achieve is to create a new column that will display a test depending on the difference value.
Here is a example:

```
Col1     Col2      Difference     Percentage        Action
 200        0            -200            100        DROPPED
 100      100               0              0        
   0      300             300            100        ADDED
```

How can create this action column. Calculated member only want some amount value so I cannot output a text in the formula.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: how about taking a new crosstab and taking `Action` column in that crosstab?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your idea. The Action column content depend on the value of the other column, so I will have to completely replicate the corsstab

Comment: My idea is taking different and setting the secrion of the crosstab to relative position will help you get 2nd cross tab coming exactly at the end of the first crosstab. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
I can use the Display string formula in the Format Field properties (Common Tab). Here I just check the column and return the string I want otherwise I just format the number.

```
IF GetColumnGroupIndexOf(CurrentColumnIndex) = 1 
   AND CurrentColumnIndex =4 THEN
   IF GridValueAt(CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex,CurrentSummaryIndex) =2 THEN "DROPPED"
   ELSE "ADDED"
ELSE
   ToText( GridValueAt(CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex,CurrentSummaryIndex),2,",")
```